# How do you call a global variable within implementation files in Objective-C

Tags: objective-c

Lets say I want a BOOL to indicate the status of something.
Then I call a class method that uses a recursive function to construct a certain string.
Is there anyway to keep this BOOL outside of the class method so that it's status can change outside of the recursion?
I'm finding a hard to ask this question clearly but I'm hoping you guys know what I'm trying to ask :/

Comment: can you paste some code supporting your question ??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two primitive approaches:

---

1) Visible to multiple files:

**MONGlobalBOOL.h**

```
extern BOOL MONGlobalBOOL;
```

**MONGlobalBOOL.m**

```
BOOL MONGlobalBOOL = NO;
```

---

2) Visible to one file:

**MONGlobalBOOL.m**

```
static BOOL MONGlobalBOOL = NO;
```

You don't want this in your headers because that will just emit a copy of the variable for each translation.

---

In use:

```
+ (void)method
{
  if (MONGlobalBOOL) {
    ...
  }
}
```

---

Careful, global mutable data frequently decays to evil stuff. You can likely solve your exact problem by creating a local variable on the stack.

Answer (score 1):

As far as language support goes, anything that can be done in C can be done in Objective C.  So you probably just want to use a static variable:

```
static BOOL globalFlag
```

Of course, if you only want to reference the variable within the recursive method, as in you want to send a flag to a calling method from a deeper recursion of the method, then you may do better passing the variable by reference:

```
- (void)someMethodWithRecursionFlag:(BOOL *)recursionFlag;
```

and then setting it by reference when needed:

```
*recursionFlag = YES;
```

and reading it when you're interested in it:

```
[self someMethodWithRecursionFlag:recursionFlag];
if (*recursionFlag)
    [self doSomethingInteresting];
```